# Neo4j v2.2.3 Embedded HA: can't create cluster

Tags: neo4j, high-availability

I have an embedded Neo4j v2.2.3 three identical server setup, where I'm trying to turn a single database into a HA setup. I've tried beginning the HA process with every combination of databases: all empty, all-but-one empty and all using the same database, but to no avail. AFAIK for some reason the Neo4j instances can't connect to each other. I have verified that the IP addresses are correct, and the port 5001 should be open. I've also opened 6001 for.

Here is my messages.log.

```
2015-06-25 20:37:16.461+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: --- INITIALIZED diagnostics START ---
2015-06-25 20:37:16.462+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Neo4j Kernel properties:
2015-06-25 20:37:16.467+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: ha.server_id=1
2015-06-25 20:37:16.467+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: ha.server=:6001
2015-06-25 20:37:16.467+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: online_backup_server=0.0.0.0:6362
2015-06-25 20:37:16.467+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: ephemeral=false
2015-06-25 20:37:16.467+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: ha.initial_hosts=[IP1]:5001,[IP2]:5001,[IP3]:5001
2015-06-25 20:37:16.467+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: online_backup_enabled=true
2015-06-25 20:37:16.468+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: ha.cluster_server=:5001
2015-06-25 20:37:16.468+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: store_dir=/var/neo4j
2015-06-25 20:37:16.468+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
2015-06-25 20:37:16.468+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: org.neo4j.server.database.mode=HA
2015-06-25 20:37:16.469+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Diagnostics providers:
2015-06-25 20:37:16.469+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config
2015-06-25 20:37:16.469+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: org.neo4j.kernel.info.DiagnosticsManager
2015-06-25 20:37:16.469+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: SYSTEM_MEMORY
2015-06-25 20:37:16.469+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: JAVA_MEMORY
2015-06-25 20:37:16.469+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: OPERATING_SYSTEM
2015-06-25 20:37:16.469+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: JAVA_VIRTUAL_MACHINE
2015-06-25 20:37:16.469+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: CLASSPATH
2015-06-25 20:37:16.469+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: LIBRARY_PATH
2015-06-25 20:37:16.469+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: SYSTEM_PROPERTIES
2015-06-25 20:37:16.469+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: LINUX_SCHEDULERS
2015-06-25 20:37:16.469+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: NETWORK
2015-06-25 20:37:16.469+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: NodeCache
2015-06-25 20:37:16.469+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: RelationshipCache
2015-06-25 20:37:16.469+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: HighAvailabilityDiagnostics
```

....

```
2015-06-25 21:55:36.502+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: High Availability diagnostics
Member state:PENDING
State machines:
   AtomicBroadcastMessage:start
   AcceptorMessage:start
   ProposerMessage:start
   LearnerMessage:start
   HeartbeatMessage:start
   ElectionMessage:start
   SnapshotMessage:start
   ClusterMessage:start
Current timeouts:
```

Eventually after two minutes I get a transaction exception:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Timeout waiting for database to become available and allow new transactions. Waited 2m. 2 reasons for blocking: Database is stopped, Cluster state is 'PENDING'.
```

I create a `graphDatabaseFactory = new HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory()` which is used to create

```
DatabaseServiceImpl(
    graphDatabaseFactory
      .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(neo4jStoreDir)
      .loadPropertiesFromFile(configFileLocation)
      .newGraphDatabase())
```

This is what my neo4j.properties looks like:

```
online_backup_enabled=true
online_backup_server=0.0.0.0:6362
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
org.neo4j.server.database.mode=HA
ha.server_id=1
ha.cluster_server=0.0.0.0:5001
ha.server=0.0.0.0:6001
ha.initial_hosts=[IP1]:5001,[IP2]:5001,[IP3]:5001
```

I've tried a lot of different combinations for the properties and also added the [suggested](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha-setup-tutorial.html) values from neo4-server.properties but nothing helps. Where should I put neo4j-server.properties in embedded mode, or are they not needed (that's my initial guess)?

What might be wrong? Is it even possible to setup a HA cluster using embedded Neo4j anymore?

EDIT. I made sure every server is on the same subnet and the servers can connect to each other without obstructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem turned out to be that I'm using kernel extensions set with `new HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory().addKernelExtensions(myKernelExtensionsArray)`. The `addKernelExtensions` method is deprecated, but these extensions work great with a single server setup. However on this HA server setup they fail for some reason.

I was able to reuse my kernel extensions by replacing a call to `addKernelExtensions` with `registerTransacionEventHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j definitely supports clustering in embedded mode - you can even mix server and embedded instances in the same cluster.

You don't need the settings from `neo4j-server.properties` at all when running in embedded mode.

Some things to check:

1. make sure the 3 cluster members are on the same subnet. If they aren't and they're physically dislocated, consider establishing a VPN (e.g. via openvpn) to have them on the same subnet.
2. Allow any IP traffic in between the cluster members, they will open up additional ports.

Comment: Thanks! Wrt: "they will open up additional ports", I have currently only the 5001 and 6001 ports open, but can open up a port range. Is there any way of knowing which ports Neo4j tries to open?

Comment: The recommended setting is to enable any communication between the cluster members. Being too picky might lead to hard-to-debug trouble if e.g. a future version of Neo4j changes implementation regarding communication channels.

Comment: I'm trying to run this on Docker, where it seems to be currently impossible to expose every port. It might be that the problem is the ha.server and ha.cluster_server settings. I don't quite understand what they are, or can I set them to 0.0.0.0 or should I use something else.

I have a MongoDB cluster running on the same machines successfully, inside containers, so there shouldn't be any IP issues. Other than I don't know which ports to expose. I tried 5000-7000, but that didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you can check this docker setup for some ideas / hints: https://github.com/ekino/docker-neo4j-cluster

Comment: Thanks for the link, hadn't found it myself! Unfortunately it's using a DNS located on the same machine. That might work, but another option would be an ambassador thing, as was advised in this identical problem here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Neo4j/comments/349sev/neo4j_ha_behind_docker/
The oddest thing is that in there are logs about HA: my messages.log doesn't contain any errors about HA. Which makes me wonder is HA setup properly in the first place? The only HA-related info in my messages.log is the "High Availability diagnostics" thing, but nothing else is printed.

Comment: Ok, I haven't been able to test it but the problem is that the servers aren't on the same subnet. Luckily I'm on CoreOS, which means I was able to create a subnet with flannel really easily. The problem is that the IP address for each custom Neo4j server is not known until the Docker container is started. That means that I have to create a polling loop before I launch Neo4j to get ha.initial_hosts filled. I'll report back with an answer once I get it to work and verify that it is the problem.

Comment: Well now the Neo4j containers are all running on the same subnet, but nothing changed: there are still no traces of anything happening in messages.log after "High Availability diagnostics". This is really annoying.